# Node JS VPN [Electron]

Tags: node.js, vpn, electron

Добрый день.

У меня встал такой вопрос.

Как реализовать подключение к VPN на NodeJS.

Open VPN, PPTP, L2TP - Не имеет значения.

Заранее благодарю.